# How to self-leave Directories in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to leave unused directories from Azure portal. I need only Default Directory.
Some of directories have been unused for 3 years.

How can I can leave directory with out help of admin of another directory?

Answer (score 7):

To extend [Rickvdbosch answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084367/13386907):

If you're using a personal Microsoft account you'll need to specify the Tenant name or id that you want to leave.

For example: https://myaccount.microsoft.com?tenantId=wingtiptoys.onmicrosoft.com or https://myaccount.microsoft.com?tenantId=ab123456-cd12-ef12-gh12-ijk123456789.

Then follow the previous instructions after you've signed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to myaccount.microsoft.com -> Manage organizations: https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations.

Here you can click the Leave organization button for all tenants you'd like to leave from.

Comment: This doesn't work when you are using a personal Microsoft Account.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to [Juunas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084076/1945525):

If you're using a Microsoft Account there's a different portal you need to visit. Go to the [Organizations section](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/profile/organizations#organizations-section) of *account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com*, sign in to the organization you want to leave and click *Leave organization*.

After clicking *Sign in to leave* you might need to close the new experience if you're in it. To do so:

1. Click the profile icon on the top right.
2. Click the three dots next to *Switch organization*.
3. Click *Leave new experience*.
4. Click the profile picture and then the cog next to *Organizations*. This leads you back to the *Organizations section* I linked to above for the organization you just signed in to.
5. Leave the organization by clicking *Leave organization*.

Comment: I just tried this and got an Access Denied with the extra detail: "Important: This page does not yet support signing in with a Microsoft account. If you have one already, try signing in again using an account assigned to you by your organization. If you don’t have one, please request a new work or school account from your admin, and then try again."